# Android package.xml missing from /data/system

Tags: android

I am developing android application. I was trying to use **pm list packages** command  to know list of installed packages. But I am getting this command as unrecognized.All other adb comands are working. Also **package.xml** is not present /data/system directory. Why can it be the case? And what can be done to get it?

Comment: adb shell pm list packages and its /data/system/packages.xml

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean **packages.xml** (**NOT package.xml**)? It is under `/data/system/`directory, and contains all the information of installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

On recent android systems the packages.xml file is in /dbdata/system instead of /data/system.

Don't know about pm list packages.

Answer (score 0):

in my case package.xml is there in data/system path it includes all the package lists with permissions

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to execute pm list packages command ? Android SDK provide PackageManager class which provide all details about installed application/package. In Android normal user call application but in system it refere as Package. so Package and application both are same. Using package manager you can get app name , icon, size, and many details.

Following link will help you to get packages/applications.

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html
2. http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon